# Discrete Fast Radon Transform Transpose for Optimization Algorithm

Tags: discrete-optimization, quadratic-programming, radon-transform

The radon transform of an image $f(x,y)$ can be written as:

\begin{equation}
p(\alpha,s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x(z),y(z))dz \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z\sin\alpha+s\cos \alpha , -z\cos \alpha + s \sin \alpha)dz
\end{equation}

The discrete matrix version of this equation can be written as
\begin{equation}
R \vec{f}=\vec{p}
\end{equation}

Where $R$ is a matrix, $\vec{f}$ is the image vector and $\vec{p}$ is the radon transform vector. I'm seeking to find the continuous analogue to $RR^T\vec{f}$.

**Maybe irrelevant context:**
I'm creating an quadratic optimization algorithm where I need to quickly calculate the minimum of $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+b^Tx$ subject to $x\geq 0$ where
\begin{equation}
A=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
RR^T & -RR^T\\ 
-RR^T & RR^T
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b=\begin{bmatrix}
R\vec{f}\\ 
1-R\vec{f}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}